# Onchange submit, update DB & display result in place of the dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, forms

I have a dropdown list of drivers names, when the dispatcher selects a drivers name it needs to update the DB and then display the contents of that column in the database in place of the dropdown list.

This is what I have so far and have no idea where to go from here.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  dispatch WHERE driver = '' OR pu_time = '' OR do_time = ''";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $i = 0;
        $color1 = "#ff0000";
        $color2 = "#00ff00";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            if($i%2 == 1) {$color = $color1;}
                else {$color = $color2;}

                echo "<tr style='background-color: $color'>";
                echo '<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" />'.$row['call_time'].'</td>';
                echo "<td>".$row['start_address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['end_address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['puat']."</td>";

                    if (isset($row['driver']) === true && empty($row['driver']) === true){

                        echo '<td>
                             <form id = "driver">
                              <select name="driver">
                              <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
                              <option value="Cheek">Cheek</option>
                              <option value="Spencer">Spencer</option>
                              <option value="Melissa">Melissa</option>
                            </select>
                            </form></td>';

                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<td>".$row['driver']."</td>";
                            }

                echo "</tr>";
                $i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX (I see jQuery tagged, so jQuery's AJAX will do the trick) -- hook into the `select` elements `onchange` event (or .change()` with jQuery)

Comment: I sort of get it, and have looked at some examples, however all of them use a different file to process the form... and I need to stay on the same page. or am I misunderstanding. Admittedly I know absolutely nothing of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very crude work around... If anyone has a better idea I am open to it!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  dispatch WHERE driver = '' OR pu_time = '' OR do_time = ''";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $i = 0;
        $color1 = "#ff0000";
        $color2 = "#00ff00";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            if($i%2 == 1) {$color = $color1;}
                else {$color = $color2;}

                echo "<tr style='background-color: $color'>";
                echo '<td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" />'.$row['call_time'].'</td>';
                echo "<td>".$row['start_address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['end_address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['phone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['puat']."</td>";

                    if (isset($row['driver']) === true && empty($row['driver']) === true){

                        echo '<td>
                             <form id = "driver">
                              <select name="driver" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                              <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
                              <option value="Cheek">Cheek</option>
                              <option value="Spencer">Spencer</option>
                              <option value="Melissa">Melissa</option>
                            </select>
                            </form></td>';
                                if (isset($_GET['driver'])){
                                    $new_driver = $_GET['driver'];
                                    $id = $row['id'];
                                    $update_d = "UPDATE dispatch SET driver = '$new_driver' WHERE id = '$id'";
                                    mysql_query($update_d,$con)
                                    or die;
                                    unset($_GET['driver']);
                                    echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">
                                            window.location.href = "new_index.php";
                                          </script>';
                                    }
                        }
                        else {

                            echo $_GET['driver']."Hello";
                            echo "<td>".$row['driver']."</td>";
                            }



                echo "</tr>";
                $i++;
        }
    }
```